# solve an integral equation

Tags: integral-equations, transcendental-equations

Given a continuous function $f$ and an equation:
$$
\int_0^1 e^{xf(t)} dt -1 = 0 ,
$$
check if a positive solution $x$ exists and find it if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)=0$, any $x$ is a solution.  Otherwise, let $$g(x) = \int_0^1 e^{xf(t)} dt -1$$, then $$g''(x)=\int_0^1 f^2(t)e^{xf(t)} dt > 0$$, therefore $g$ is convex. On the other hand, $g(0)=0$.  Therefore, $g(x)=0$ has a positive root iff $g'(0)<0$ and $g(x)>0$ for some $x$.

The first condition is $$ \int_0^1 f(t)dt < 0 $$

The second condition never obeys if $f(t)\le 0$ everywhere on $[0,1]$.  If there is a point $t \in [0,1]$ for which $f(t)>0$, there is an interval $[a,b]$ around $t$ at which $f>f(t)/2$.  It is easy to prove that for sufficiently large $x$, $\int_a^b e^{xf(t)} dt$ can be made arbitrary large, so the second condition obeys.

So the complete condition is either $f(t)=0$ at the whole $[0,1]$ (1), or $ \int_0^1 f(t)dt < 0 $ (2), and $f(t)>0$ for some $t\in [0,1]$ (3).

In case of (1), any $x$ is a root.  In case of (2) and (3), $x$ can be found as a zero of any convex function.

Comment: +1: Nice. ${}{}{}$

Comment: The original question asks to find x, any idea of how to do so?

Comment: @Ivan read the last sentence. There are several algorithms to find zeros of a convex function.

Comment: Do you mean numerical algorithms? I am not aware of any analytical techniques. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ivan - Yes, I mean numerican algorithms. I don't know how to solve this analytically, or whether it is possible.